# Instagram API - how to request more permissions for a Live client?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We have a production app using the Instagram API - currently with only the `basic` permission scope approved. A couple of months down the line, we are now adding further functionality which requires the `public_content` permission. During development, I have used a new Sandbox Client ID, but now I'd like to have the current Live app submitted to request the `public_content` permission so that I can make the new functionality available to it. The [Sandbox mode](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) documentation states:

> If you need access to more permissions, you can submit for review again and you will not lose access to the permissions that you have already been granted.

My question is: **How can I submit a request for more permissions from Instagram when the Client is already out of Sandbox Mode?**

The fact that it is already out of Sandbox Mode (with basic permissions), means that I cannot demonstrate the new functionality - after all, already being Live means I cannot authorise `public_content` from users. Instagram state `We only review final and production version apps. Submissions with test and development version apps will not be approved.` I don't see how this can be achieved?

I'm assuming that in this scenario, Instagram either does not expect you to have the functionality live (and perhaps a description/video will suffice for the extra permissions). Either that or they expect you to submit a new Sandbox app which demonstrates the functionality - but then this clearly won't be a production app. I'm clearly missing something, and the lack of documentation on this from Instagram isn't helping.

Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Were you able to request additional permission for your live client? Or did you have to create a separate app?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same process you used before. Click the "Manage" button for your client then, click "Start Submission" button under the "Permissions" tab. You'll need a new video demoing the permissions you want. This means, you need to set up the Sandbox so  you actually can demo your use case for the permissions you want (fun stuff! lol).

**Protip:** Save your submission to a Word document so you can amend it. I made the mistake of not saving my original submission so when I went back, I had to work hard to make sure my language was in compliance with the use cases and stuff.

It's pretty simple to do what you want to do since you've already gotten through the approval process once - getting the sandbox set up can be tricky unless you have friend who will accept your sandbox invites (feel free to invite me @mikeghen, I'll accept).

If you're getting rejected, reread the use case you're applying for, make sure you actually can get the permissions you want using that use case, and then reread your document with the submission you submitted, you probably aren't being clear (**Protip:** don't say too much, be concise and let the video do the talking). I kind of feel silly for asking a similar question: [Adding Features to Approve Instagram Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916226/adding-features-to-approve-instagram-client)

Again, setting up a new Sandbox is probably where your struggling.

**Protip:** I suggest making another client (so you have a dev and production client) and then get the permissions you need using the dev client. Once you get the permissions you need, dev becomes production and production becomes dev.

Thank you for highlighting that line in the Sandbox docs, I didn't see that before. But I think that answers my question.

Comment: Very much appreciate the response! Given that my current production client can only be in one mode or the other (Sandbox or Live) - it seems the only way I can demonstrate the functionality is with a new client as you suggest. 
The issue I see here is that the new client will not be in production yet (where IG seems to require that the app is not on a test or staging server), and perhaps more importantly: if it's the new client that gets approved - it'll mean everyone would need to log in again, and would then have permissions for both apps in their profile. Do you have thoughts on this?

Comment: The best scenario would seem to be that I submit a new client in Sandbox mode which demonstrate the new functionality and permissions - but then somehow communicate the Instagram that if approved - I'd like the permissions granted for my original, currently Live client. Alternatively, to request the permissions on the original client - but in the description, include the video of the Sandbox client demonstrating it, and explain why in the description. Do you or anyone else know if either approach would work?

Comment: I store my key and secret as environmental variables and just swap them out on my production server. People need to log in again but it hasn't been a big deal. You probably need to go back to the drawing board for you login flow if that's a hang up for you. JFYI, don't hard code your key and secret into your application code, that's a bad security practice. They should be stored as environmental variables on the server.

Comment: Don't forget to approve this answer if it answered your question :)

Comment: Hello Mike - I appreciate your response here - it doesn't quite answer my question fully - so I'm holding out for which explicitly answers the issues surrounding the exact concerns I have tried to clarify in my comments here.

Comment: Don't have an answer for you, unfortunately, but I need to do the same. The only solution I can see is creating the separate sandbox app, getting it approved by indicating in the use case / comments that the permissions need to be applied to your original app. Or maybe mention it in the screen cast aswel.