# Adding Features to Approve Instagram Client

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an approved Instagram client (i.e. my app was reviewed an is live) and I wanted to add a new feature to the application. I've heard some applications were getting their clients revoked and I want to know, can I proactively submit my new features for approval before pushing them into production? Does anyone have any experience with this?

I just want to avoid the plug being pulled because my customers pay for my application and use it daily. I'd like to avoid any service interruption. My thought was to email someone on the Instagram API team but, I can't find an email.

What I'm going to do is create a new client and submit a new video with the new features demoed in sandbox, I think this is the best thing to do but I wanted to post here first to find out if anyone has some experience to share that might help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to add features to the app and resubmit for approval?

Comment: Yes, I created a new app and submitted for approval that way. Now I have two clients, one with more privileges than the other.

Comment: Did you managed to get all the privileges you needed with one client, or do you need to switch between these two clients, depending on the request? Facing the same situation here and i would like to avoid calling two different clients based on the permission needed for the Instagram endpoints